# Horizontal Alignment of Equations w/ Comment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I'm working on a homework assignment and would like to add a comment to one of the steps I've taken.  When I do, however, the alignment of everything is thrown off.  Is there a way to center the equations to the page and then have the comment align to the right margin?  See picture below.

```
\begin{align*}
x_1+x_2&=1\\
x_1+(-1)&=1 &&\text{(Recall, $x_2=-1$ from above)}\\
x_1&=2
\end{align*}
```

[image: document picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flalign*` with the right number of  `&`, and `\llap` for the comments:

```
\begin{flalign*}
 & & x_1+x_2&=1\\
 & & x_1+(-1)&=1 &&\llap{(Recall, $x_2=-1$ from above)}\\
 & & x_1&=2
\end{flalign*}
```

[image]

Comment: Nailed it!  Works perfectly, you always come through!  Thanks, @Bernard!